# Subquery in Case statement using value from outer select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, case

I have got two tables, something like what is shown below

[image]

I need to write a select query, which when comes across a Mat_Name from category P11 or P12, and has last four characters anything other than 'B111' (for ex. AA-1234-B333), then it should give out Mat_Num of some other Mat_Name which has the same first eight characters, but has 'B111' as its last 4 characters ie. in case of AA-1234-B333 it should return Mat_Num as 123456, which is Mat_Num for AA-1234-B111, and not 114466.

I was thinking of using the below query, but then I couldn't quite figure out passing value of Mat_Name from outer select to the one inside the CASE statement (to get correct Mat_Num).

```
select tbl1.Mat_Name,
CASE  
    When (tbl2.Category IN ('P11','P12')) AND (RIGHT(tbl.Mat_Name,4) <> 'B111') THEN (Select tbl1.Mat_Num from tbl1 where ... ),
 tbl2.Category
from tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tb1.Mat_Num = tbl2.Mat_Num
```

Comment: solved it by using a CTE

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that can return a single, atomic value - it is **not** a statement (that can control flow of your application) .....